# How to replace the value of a JSON node in ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

I've got a simple JSON string in ruby, which I manage to successfully load as a JSON Hash as follows:

```
@json_hash = Json.parse(json_string)
```

where 'json_string' is quite basic:

```
{"key1"=>"string_value_1", "key2"=1000}
```

Could you guide me to how I could replace for example the 1000 value if 'key2' equals 'key_found'?

I'm trying with:

```
    @json_hash.each {|k,v| v = 9999 if k == 'key_found'}
```

but when I debug my code for the value of @json_hash, I can see that the 'key2' value is still 1000 rather than 9999?

Many thank!!!

Comment: don't CHANGE values of collection inside `each`. It is an iteration, not an evaluation. you should use, for example, simple access to node via subscription, e.g. `hash[key] = value`

Comment: gaussblurinc, thank you man!

I started trying that, but I didn't create json_hash at the time, I was directly trying to replace from 'Json.parse(json_string)' and when I was checking 'json_string' it had the original value... 

Now that you mention it, tried again with json_hash instead and that kept the value

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `JSON.parse` is an ordinary Ruby object (a hash here). You can access it like any other Ruby hash. In your case:

```
@json_hash['key_found'] = 9999
```

Comment: thank you both, I was getting confused as mentioned to gaussblurinc above... much appreciated!